# find out the missing images in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two folders which one folder contains 8000 images (`F_0001.jpg`, `F_0002.jpg`,...) and another one 8363 images (`F_0001.tiff`, `F_0002.tiff`, ...).

I need to find out which images are missing in the first folder and remove them from the second one! filenames are the same on both folders!

Below is my code, I wrote it but I can't find the logic how to find out the name of the missing images in the first folder

```py
img_rgb_path = '/home/train/RGB/'
img_ther_path = '/home/train/thermal_16_bit/'

rgb = sorted(glob.iglob(os.path.join(img_rgb_path, '*.jpg')))
ther = sorted(glob.iglob(os.path.join(img_ther_path, '*.tiff')))
print(len((rgb))) # 8000 images
print(len(there)) # 8363 images

for rgb, ther in zip(rgb, ther):
    fullname_rgb = ntpath.split(rgb)[-1]
    fullname_ther = ntpath.split(ther)[-1]
    # Dont know what to do after .... :|
```

Comment: I think using `dircmp` from `filecmp` will help you to achieve your result

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over second folder and check whether image exists in first one:

```
import os
import glob

FOLDER1 = '/home/train/RGB'
FOLDER2 = '/home/train/thermal_16_bit'

for img2 in glob.glob(os.path.join(FOLDER2, '*.tiff')):
    img1 = os.path.join(FOLDER1, os.path.basename(img2).replace('.tiff', '.jpg'))
    if not os.path.isfile(img1):
        os.remove(img2)
```